# Terminal reset troubles

Tags: bash, terminal, shell, mingw

According to the MinGW setup program, I have the bash shell installed. When I attempt to issue a `reset`, I get:

```
sh: reset: command not found
```

Bash responds to the `reset` command in every other environment I've worked it, and I'm having trouble getting `reset` to work under MinGW.

I tried to ensure that `bash` is used rather than `sh`, but I can't seem to make heads or tails of [6.2 Bash Startup Files](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html). I looked for a `passwd` and shadow `passwd` file, but there does not appear to be one. So the best I can tell, I have a bash that's not being used as bash due to an unknown process or influence...

I also tried sending the command `echo -e \\033c` and <kbd>CTLRL</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> called out by [4. Resetting your terminal](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Keyboard-and-Console-HOWTO-4.html), but that does not work as expected. ("Does not work" is an exercise left to MinGW users to see the effects).

I also have the `gettext` and `ncurses` packages installed.

I have two ***simple*** questions:

1. How do I ensure "bash" bash is always used, and not some variation like "sh" bash
2. How do I invoke the reset command to clear the terminal?

Above, when I say "clear", its meant as a description, and not the command. I want to erase everything that's on the screen and in the scrollback history.

Comment: I haven't seen an ncurses package for mingw.